# Cygwin messes up Windows PATH

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, path, environment-variables

I installed Cygwin and uninstalled it after some time on a Windows 7 machine. But, the `PATH` variable directories naming is not correct now. Could some one tell me how do I correct this? Log below - notice the path starts with `/cygdrive/` instead of `C:/`.

```
PATH=/cygdrive/c/windows:/cygdrive/c/windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/windows/system32/wbem:/cygdrive/c/program files/common files/microsoft shared/microsoft online services:
```

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `%windir%\System32\SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe`

Click the Environment Variables button

[image]

Then under **System Variables** choose **PATH** and press **Edit**.

[image]

You can then edit all instances of `/cygdrive/c/` with `C:\`

Comment: I tried,  it is okay in system variables settings, but the issue is that when I type ENV in DOS prompt, the PATH has /cygdrive/ pprefix for all paths.

Comment: @user270066 if you had the CMD window open before you made the changes, the System Variable changes won't propagate to that console.  Open a new CMD window, and the path should be correct there . . .